# Using GeoServer WMS-T with QGIS TimeManager?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, timemanager, wms-time

I have a GeoServer layer that was generated from a Cassandra database via the GeoMesa api. When I run a WMS query such as the following with changing &TIME parameter values, the openlayers page for each time slice shows the data points correctly for each timestamp:

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mygeomesademo/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=mygeomesademo:mygeomesademo&styles=&bbox=-265.78125,-128.67188,266.48438,130.78125&width=768&height=374&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers&TIME=2018-01-08T09:40:00Z/2018-01-08T09:46:00Z

Now I was hoping I could use the QGIS time manager plugin to vary the time parameters and run these queries in succession to do autoplayback. When I create a connection, and add the layer as WMS/WMTS, the layer is available to TM as "Add raster".

My question is, does the TM plugin call WMS in the way that I am showing in the REST uri above for a raster layer, varying the time parameters, or does it only do this for vector layers?

QGIS 2.14.20, GeoServer 2.12

Comment: One thing I see in the log is "Could not guess timestamp in raster filename. Cause 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'
2018-02-28T09:45:03 0". But the thing is, afterwards, the TM plugin does display the FIRST time slice value correctly for the layer, which makes sense since the layer has a time dimension configured, and is set to "smallest domain value" as the default. So the fact that it displays the first time slice seems to be proof the TM plugin *is* making the WMS call behind the scenes, even for a raster layer? But how, or is it possible to, have the time parameters populated.ty

Comment: Is there anyway to turn on debugging for TM in order to see what WMS calls are being made? It seems like the setTimeRestriction() function in wmstlayer.py is adding a TIME parameter to the WMS uri with the altered time parameters entered for the raster layer, but I do not see any data displayed when I click the play button

Comment: Hmm I printed the dataUrl variable from the setTimeRestriction() function which was: "dataUrl: IgnoreGetFeatureInfoUrl=1&IgnoreGetMapUrl=1& table="" sql=?TIME=2018-01-08T14:40:00Z/2018-01-08T14:46:00Z". I was expecting a WMS URL like what I have posted above, so perhaps this function is not doing what I thought it was as far as a WMS REST call goes

Comment: WMS are not RESTful

Answer (score 1):

Yes, TimeManager does work with GeoServer WMS-T. An example is shown in https://anitagraser.com/2015/08/10/using-timemanager-for-wms-t-layers/.

[image]

I've also used TimeManager successfully with GeoMesa layers in GeoServer. https://anitagraser.com/2017/08/27/getting-started-with-geomesa-using-geodocker/

It is important to use the correct timestamp format. In GeoServer WMS-T, timestamps look like: `2005-08-29T03:10:00Z`. (As I understand it, the standard would allow for other formats as well but QGIS/TimeManager do not check the WMS server's capabilities with respect to time settings.)